# How can I install a USB bluetooth dongle in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, bluetooth

I would like to use a USB bluetooth dongle on Ubuntu 12.04. I guess that I will have install some drivers first. So where do I get those? Are there any universal bluetooth drivers?

Do I have to do anything else to this working?

EDIT: When I run `lsusb` I get the following result:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a12:100b Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Just in case: I am running Ubuntu in VirtualBox.

P.S.: I am using this USB bluetooth dongle: Sitecom CN-524
http://www.sitecom.com/lu/micro-bluetooth-40-usb-adapter/cn-524/p/1531

Comment: The dongle should work without any drivers. If it does not, open a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T and type `lsusb` and hit enter. Then copy the output **by editing your original question above.**

Comment: @user68186 I edited my question. Does that help you to help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install drivers present in the aditional drivers in order to use USB's in virtualBox.

If your bluetooth is still not working then check addtional drivers to see if you have to install more drivers for the USB Dongle

Comment: no luck with that one :(